# Determining a limit of an integral function

Tags: integration, limits

I'm trying to determine the limit of the following:

$$ \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac 1 h \int_{x}^{x+h} \frac 1 {\sqrt {1 +t^6}}dt $$

It is hard to determine the anti derivative of what is inside the integral so that didn't seem like an option. I tried to compute it through Mathematica but it took ages to compute and came up with a really weird answer. I also noticed that $\frac 1 h$ tends to infinity and the integral tends to $0$, but I don't know how to determine which of them is 'stronger'.

Can someone provide any help (hints?)?

Comment: Think of it as a derivative of $F(z) = \int_a^z ... dt$ at $z=x$.  Then it is easy from the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^6}}$ is decreasing (towards zero) on $\mathbb{R}^+$. So you are considering the limit as $h\to 0$ of a quantity that is between $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(x+h)^6}}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^6}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Using l'Hopital
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\int_{x}^{x+h} \frac 1 {\sqrt {1 +t^6}}dt}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{ \frac 1 {\sqrt {1 +(x+h)^6}}}{1}= \frac 1 {\sqrt {1 +x^6}}$$

Comment: Out of curiosity, how might one go about finding an anti-derivative for $\frac 1{\sqrt{1+t^6}}$ ?

Comment: So your taking the derivative of both terms with respect to `dh` right?

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+1%2Fsqrt(1%2Bx%5E6)) suggests this would be quite difficult (lol your name)

Comment: Huh, you're right. Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasW Respect to $h$ only

Comment: @ThomasW Are you familiar with Leibniz integral rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: I think $$\int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^n}}$$ is easy to solve only for $n = -2,-1,0,1,2$.

Comment: @MyGlasses ah yes thank you. I was familiar but not with the partial differentiation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you define $$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \frac 1 {\sqrt {1 +t^6}}\,dt$$
Then $$F(x+h)-F(x)=\int_{0}^{x+h} \frac 1 {\sqrt {1 +t^6}}\,dt-\int_{0}^{x} \frac 1 {\sqrt {1 +t^6}}\,dt=\int_{x}^{x+h} \frac 1 {\sqrt {1 +t^6}}\,dt$$
And the limit is $$\lim \limits_{h \to 0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}=F'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^6}}$$

The primitive $F(x)$ actually can be expressed only with special functions and it is very hard

Hope this helps